# How is session caching affected by the renewal of a ssl certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, cache, session

I optimized my [nginx session cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache) like this

```
# Optimize session cache
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:40m;
ssl_session_timeout 4h;
```

In a few days my Let's Encrypt certificate will be renewed. Does this have any negative influence on my SSL configuration? Could user be blocked from my site or something like this? Or has the session cache nothing to do with the certificate? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I suspect the answer to this question will often be irrelevant in practice: You (or your certificate renewal routine) will reload your web server to apply the new certificate, and in doing so discard the in-memory session cache.

Comment: This happens automatically?